# Conditional creation of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with Chartjs and trying to create the chart object once within a function. Then skipping that piece of code in the function so it will just update the chart on future calls.

I am not not sure how to structure the conditional chart object creation. Below is my code approach ( it does not run atm).

```
class BtcOverview extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();

  }


 componentDidMount () {

    this.callApi();

  } 


  callApi = () => {

    fetch(getApi())
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(marketData => {

      //API FETCH STUFF


    const chartOptions = {
      ...{}
      ...this.props.chartOptions
    };

    const BtcChart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, {
      type: "LineWithLine",
      data: this.props.chartData,
      options: chartOptions
    });




    BtcChart.render(); 

    // I want to create the BtcChart and render() on the first run. But then after that only call update() on the chart object

     }) 
  }



  render() {

    return (
     <>
          <CardBody className="pt-2">
            <canvas
              height="160"
              ref={this.canvasRef}
              style={{ maxWidth: "100% !important" }} className="mb-1" />

          </CardBody>  
      </Card>
    </>

    );

  }
}
```

Update: I should explain a bit more clearly. I want to be be able to create a 'new Chart' once and then on subsequent runs rather call BtcChart update given the chart object already exists.

When I tried to use an if-else statement to achieve that it would not compile because I guess because the chart BtcChart has not been created at the time of compiling and possibly a scope issue. So I am have been trying hacks that are probably wrong in their approach.

Comment: Just use and if else construction ?

Comment: Where are you calling this `update` function, could you show us the full component ?

Comment: I have updated the question to show more code.